# move many directories to another directory using CLI

Tags: directory, command-line-interface, move, pwd

I want to copy some of the directories in a directory to another directory in that directory itself.

For Example:

I have the structure like the below

```
myname@compname:~/root/app/pages$ ls

dir1, dir2, dir3
```

I want the dir1 and dir2 to be moved into dir3 and the final structure has to be as the following:

```
myname@compname:~/root/app/pages$ ls

dir3

myname@compname:~/root/app/pages/dir3$ ls

dir1, dir2
```

I know the there are many shell programs for it. but I want this to happen using the CLI itself in **just a single lined statement**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mv dir1 dir2 dir3
```

will do it

```
mv dir1 dir2
mv dir2 dir3
```

does the same thing, in two steps.

Technically `mv dir[123]` would also do the same thing (for these file names), but would potentially be confusing as the destination is determined alphabetically

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your concern. But I'm asking this in case of 100s of Directories!

Comment: for hundereds `mv * dir3`

Comment: `*` is for all the dirs. But I want the specific 100s of dir

Comment: you have to say which ones somehow,

Comment: so, any way to exclude a dir?

Comment: not easily. it's easier to move it back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the perfect answer. But i have done the above with the following code:

```
myname@compname:~/root/app/pages$ cp -r dir1/ dir3/ && cp -r dir2/ dir3/
myname@compname:~/root/app/pages$ rm -r dir1 && rm -r dir2
myname@compname:~/root/app/pages$ cd dir3 && ls
```

Other Answers are welcome!